# WKUserScript but wait for AJAX or element

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit

Using WKUserScript on iOS I’m querying some anchor tags of the DOM with JavaScript. Problem is even though the script is executed at the end of the document, the anchor tags are loaded via an AJAX call so not available when the script is run.

How to wait for the AJAX to call its success handler before executing my JavaScript?

Note: I have no access to the site page except through JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution using `.ajaxComplete( handler )` on the document. Though the document had several calls to .ajax I was able to set a Boolean that meant once certain elements were loaded it no longer executes the handler function.